# How can I force PostgreSQL to put my output in quotation marks?

Tags: bash, postgresql

I have the following code:

```
$sql = "copy(" . $sql . ") TO STDOUT CSV HEADER" ;
$cmd = "psql -h " . DATABASE_HOST . " -d " . DATABASE_NAME . " -U " . DATABASE_USER . " -c '" . $sql . ";' > " . WEBUSER_DOWNLOAD_PATH . $archivo_csv ;
```

I want the output to contain values inside quotes, for example "name", "age", ...,"any".

How can I do this?

Comment: That isn't `bash` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oof. Okay, first thing: this is probably a bad pattern. Consider, for example, what happens when `$sql` is "`DELETE FROM users) TO STDOUT; COPY (SELECT * FROM profiles`". Or, since you're issuing a bash command, something like "`SELECT 1) TO STDOUT;" rm -rf /`". Basically, this code pattern is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [Shell Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection) problems.

That said, the `COPY` command has [a bunch of options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html) nowadays. You could use something like:

```
COPY (query) TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER, FORCE_QUOTE *);
```

I'm assuming you're using a relatively current version (9.0 or later) of postgres. If you're using an older version, you might still be okay. Starting with 8.0, there was a [FORCE QUOTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-copy.html) option on the older syntax.